# Testing asset pricing models with Roll's critique in mind

Tags: asset-pricing, capm

Roll's critique ([Roll, 1977](https://www.anderson.ucla.edu/documents/areas/fac/finance/1977-2.pdf)) can be summarized as follows (quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roll%27s_critique)):

1. **Mean-variance tautology:** Any mean-variance efficient portfolio $R_{p}$ satisfies the CAPM equation exactly:
   $$
   E(R_{i})-R_{f}=\beta_{{ip}}[E(R_{p})-R_{f}].
   $$
   Mean-variance efficiency of the market portfolio is equivalent to the CAPM equation holding. This statement is a mathematical fact, requiring no model assumptions.
   Given a proxy for the market portfolio, testing the CAPM equation is equivalent to testing mean-variance efficiency of the portfolio. The CAPM is tautological if the market is assumed to be mean-variance efficient. (And [**here**](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/75823) is a question about how to interpret this, exactly.)
2. **The market portfolio is unobservable:** The market portfolio in practice would necessarily include every single possible available asset, including real estate, precious metals, stamp collections, jewelry, and anything with any worth. The returns on all possible investments opportunities are unobservable.
   From statement 1, validity of the CAPM is equivalent to the market being mean-variance efficient with respect to all investment opportunities. Without observing all investment opportunities, it is not possible to test whether this portfolio, or indeed any portfolio, is mean-variance efficient. Consequently, it is not possible to test the CAPM.

The critique sounds quite devastating, thus my **questions:**

1. Given Roll's critique, should we drop empirical tests of the CAPM?
   If not, what can be concluded from an empirical test of the CAPM?
2. Does the same or analogous critique apply to multifactor models?

Here is what I was able to find in the literature:

1. Cochrane "Asset Pricing" (revised edition, 2005) and his lecture series on YouTube – nothing.
2. Bodie, Kane and Marcus "Investments" (12th edition, 2021) present Roll's critique and then just state the following: *Given the impossibility of testing the CAPM directly, we can retreat to testing the APT...*. I take this as giving up on testing the CAPM because of the critique. But researchers have continued testing asset pricing models (including the CAPM, I think) also after 1977, so there must be something to that...
3. Campbell, Lo & MacKinlay "The Econometrics of Financial Markets" (1996) mention on p. 214-215 that
   (i) Stambaugh (1982) found the results to be insensitive to alternative versions of the benchmark portfolio and
   (ii) Kandel and Stambaugh (1987) and Shanken (1987a) find that as long as the correlation between the actual market portfolio and the proxy is above 0.70, rejection based on the proxy implies rejection based on the actual market portfolio.
   These points address the second point of Roll's critique (unobservability) but not the first one (tautology).

Comment: I believe the answer to both of your questions is "Yes". I appreciate the research and thought you have put into this and other questions surrounding this topic recently.

Comment: @amdopt, thank you for the kind words, I find them encouraging. If we should drop the tests, why has that not happened in the asset pricing literature? Fama & French still tested their 3-factor model in 1990s regardless of Roll's critique, and textbooks still present methods for testing such models (Cochrane, 2005 is one of many).

Comment: My only thought is that it's easier to reject/ignore something that is commonly rejected/ignored and move ahead with publishing work with weak foundations for the sake of publishing something. I know that sounds a little harsh, but it happens so often that I don't know what other reason there could be. I've heard/read all the justifications (as I'm sure you have), but none truly stand up to all arguments. So, to answer your question: I have no idea! :)

Comment: The critique is that you can't test the theory underlying CAPM, i.e. mean-variance optimisation over the whole set of assets. The later factor models like Fama-French   are more empirically oriented, they do not derive the model from mean-variance optimality.

Comment: The more recent asset pricing theories are also different. In particular consumption based models derived from more general preferences do not necessarily imply mean-variance efficiency. Also here the representative agent's consumption rather than the market portfolio should be pricing assets, so the issue is more about the observability of consumption rather than the observability of the market portfolio.

Comment: @fes, in your first comment, do you address point 1 or point 2? Could you elaborate on your argument and its implications (think "for dummies")? Also, how do your comments line up with Cochrane "Asset Pricing" (2005) Chapter 9 p. 151: *This is a point worth remembering: all factor models are derived as specializations of the consumption-based model. Many authors of factor model papers disparage the consumption-based model, forgetting that their factor model is the consumption-based model plus extra assumptions that allow one to proxy for marginal utility growth from some other variables.*

Comment: Roll's critique is based on a combination of 1+2. He is saying that the tests of CAPM are just testing whether that particular proxy of the market portfolio, say S&P 500, is MV efficient. The true market portfolio might still not be MV efficient even though  you find that your proxy is. Moreover, ex post some portfolio in your set of assets will always be MV efficient just by chance.

Comment: This whole notion of MV-efficiency is seen less relevant today than when Roll wrote the paper. I guess you can think of the MV model as a particular, not particularly realistic, consumption based model. But it is not how the standard CAPM is typically formulated or tested. Cochrane talks about testing consumption based models in his book, have a look. You can also see that while the MV-model is discussed, it is not emphasised too much.

Comment: @fes, hmm, but point 1 alone seems to be devastating for the CAPM. It cannot have become less relevant over time unless the model was changed or it went out of fashion (which it did, I suppose). But that is why I am asking about whether Roll's critique applies to factor models, too. And while Cochrane discusses testing factor models extensively, so I was surprised I could not find any reference to Roll's critique in is book!

Comment: If the true market portfolio were observable I don’t think we would have the types of problems discussed by Roll. Then Roll would just say that testing capm is equivalent to testing whether the market portfolio is MV efficient. I think point 1. applies to multifactor models.

Comment: @fes, thank you. If I understand correctly, the problem identified in point 1 is not that the statement "the CAPM relationship holds" implies "the market portfolio is MV efficient" but that to derive the former, we have assumed the latter. Thus, we arrive back at where we started, so that the model has no content (in other words, it is tautological). Is that right? If not, then how should I understand the last sentence in point 1?

Comment: I guess before Ross people were not aware that MV efficiency of market portfolio and CAPM are equivalent and were treating these as separate which might have caused problems. But I don’t think point 1. alone is a major  problem for capm though you should be aware of this result.

Comment: @fes, if it is not the major problem, then I probably missed the point of point 1. I think I might have misunderstood the meaning of the last sentence there. What does it really say? (I guess I can post a separate question on that...)

Comment: I meant 1. would not be a problem without 2. Have you tried to read the actual article? I think it is actually clearer than many papers.

Comment: @fes, then I really do not get point 1. From the way Roll's critique is covered in Wikipedia, it seems to me point 1 stands on its own. But that is why I posted a new question (Iink included in the updated post). I have read part of Roll's paper (quite a bit regarding point 1), but my finance knowledge probably has too many gaps so that I did not get the full picture.

Comment: The whole critique is this part of your wikipedia article: "From statement 1, validity of the CAPM is equivalent to the market being mean-variance efficient with respect to all investment opportunities. Without observing all investment opportunities, it is not possible to test whether this portfolio, or indeed any portfolio, is mean-variance efficient. Consequently, it is not possible to test the CAPM."

Comment: I think your mistake is to take these substatements as some sort of separate critiques and not read the whole critique description. This would also be clearer if you read the actual article instead of the wikipedia article. Your separate questions just adds to this confusion.

Comment: @fes, you may well be right. I have read the whole critique in the introduction of Roll's paper (but not the whole paper), in a textbook that I cite (Bodie et al.) and in Wikipedia. I liked the latter for its brevity, but it might also be the root of my trouble as it clearly separates two points and formulates point 1 in a potentially misleading manner. Thank you for your time!